# Centers of circumcircle define an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with side $a,b,c$ and angles $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$.

It holds that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma<\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

At the side $\overline{BC}$ there is an equilateral triangle $\triangle BCA''$ at the outter side, i.e. $A''$  is the point for which the points $A$ and $A''$ are on different sides of the line $BC$ and for which the triangle $\triangle BCA''$ is equilateral.

Let $A'$ be the center of the circumcircle of $\triangle BCA''$.

Similarily we define the points $B'$ and $C'$ at the lines $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{AB}$ respectively.

The radius of the circumcircle of $BCA''$ is $\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$.

It holds that $$|A'B'|^2=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma\right )$$

I want to show the following :

a) $\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma\right )=\frac{1}{2}\cos (\gamma )-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (\gamma)$

b) $A'B'C'$ is an equilateral triangle.

$$$$

First I tried to draw the above and I get :

[image]

Is that correct?

I haven't really understood how we get the angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma$. Which is this angle in the graph?

$$$$
**EDIT: **

We have that $$|A'B'|^2=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma\right )=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab \left (\frac{1}{2}\cos (\gamma )-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (\gamma)$ 
\right )$$

So do we use the cosine rule also for the other angles of the triangle to get the desired result?

Or do we show in an other way that the triangle is equilateral?

Comment: Part (b) is [Napoleon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem), supposedly discovered by the emperor himself.

Comment: The angle you are looking for is $\widehat{A'CB'}$ , which is used for the calculation of the length of $A'B'$ in $\triangle A'CB'$. And part (a) is a trigonometric identity. Have you studied cosines of sums of angles?

Comment: Ah we use the angle sum of cosine! For part (b)dowe have to calculate all angles of the triangle? Or how do we show that?@Saeed

Comment: @MaryStar Good question! Does it help to use the formula for $|A'B'|^2$ with part (a) and note that $S_{\triangle ABC} = \frac12 ab \sin \gamma$ ? That's just a guess because we are told about $|A'B'|^2$ . Let's give it a try.

Comment: Do you mean to show that all sides of the triangle have the same length? @Saeed

Comment: Using this theorem do we have to show that the triangle that is created is a rotation of a given equilateral triangle? @TonyK

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, though I don't know if it is easy to prove.

Comment: So we have that $$|A'B'|^2=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma\right )=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab\left (\frac{1}{2}\cos (\gamma )-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (\gamma)\right )$$ So do we use the cosine rule also for the other angles of the triangle to get the desired result? @Saeed

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. We know that $\frac12 ab \sin \gamma = S_{\triangle ABC}$ , so we need to show that, for example, $a^2 + b^2 -ab \cos \gamma = b^2 + c^2 - bc \cos \alpha$ .

Comment: How do we use the area $S_{\triangle ABC}$? I got stuck right now. @Saeed

Comment: @MaryStar see in the last term , ab*siny gives you $\Delta$

Comment: @MaryStar We have: $|A'B'|^2 = \frac13 (a^2 + b^2 - ab \cos \gamma) + \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}S_{\triangle ABC}$ . If we write a similar formula for $|B'C'|^2$ can we show that the two are equal?

Comment: Ah ok! Then do we have to write a similar formula for $|A'C'|$ and show that all three are equal? @Saeed

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. The answer by Lalit Tolani includes the calculations.

Comment: @MaryStar Food for thought: Is it necessary to repeat all the calculations for $|B'C'|$ and $|A'C'|$? (Answer: no)

Comment: Is it because all sides are similar? @Saeed

Comment: @MaryStar The calculations are similar. We came up with a formula based on $a, b, c$ for $A'B'$. We know that similar calculations lead to a formula based on $b, c, a$ for $B'C'$ and a formula based on $c, a, b$ for $C'A'$. And we can see that if we change the order of $a, b$ and $c$ in Lalit's answer, the end result of the calculations won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join $B'C$ and $A'C$

$\angle A'CB'=\angle A'CB+\angle BCA+\angle ACB'$

$\angle A'CB'=30^{\circ}+\gamma+30^{\circ}$

$\angle A'CB'=60^{\circ}+\gamma$

The fact used above is that the line joining circumcenter of an equilateral triangle  to any of the vertices bisects the angle corresponding to that vertex.

Now apply cosine rule on $A'CB'$

$|A'B'|^2=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma\right )=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab \left (\frac{1}{2}\cos (\gamma )-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (\gamma)
\right )=\frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2-ab\cos\gamma)+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\Delta=\frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2-\frac{b^2+a^2-c^2}{2})+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\Delta=\frac{1}{6}(a^2+b^2+c^2)+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\Delta$

Similarly

$|B'C'|^2=\frac{1}{3}b^2+\frac{1}{3}c^2-\frac{2}{3}bc\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\alpha\right )=\frac{1}{3}b^2+\frac{1}{3}c^2-\frac{2}{3}bc \left (\frac{1}{2}\cos (\alpha )-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin (\alpha)
\right )=\frac{1}{3}(b^2+c^2-bc\cos\alpha)+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\Delta=\frac{1}{3}(b^2+c^2-\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2})+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\Delta=\frac{1}{6}(a^2+b^2+c^2)+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\Delta$

Clearly above two side lengths are equal therefore.....

Comment: I got it! Thank you!! As for part (b) do we have to show that all angles of the triangle are equal?

Comment: Or do we have to show that all sides of the triangle are equal? Maybe using $|A'B'|^2=\frac{1}{3}a^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2-\frac{2}{3}ab\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{3}+\gamma\right )$ and part (a) ?

Comment: @MaryStar sorry for late reply , I think it would be easier to show sides to be equal rather than involving angles, what do you think?

Comment: Do we use the cosine rule for that and part (a) ?

Comment: @MaryStar part (a) is an identity, just use it. For next part use cosine rule

Comment: @MaryStar see my answer, you may now get it

Comment: Then we do the same for $|A'C'|$ and we see that all are equal, right?

Comment: @MaryStar yes we do same for $A'C'$

Comment: @MaryStar if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)